# How to Update When a value equals the max value?

Tags: php, sql, max

Im trying to run this query to Update member points When the member points equals the max value? to set the winner prize... but im getting this error.. thanks

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE a.points = max(a.points) AND b.event_id = 4' at line 4

```
    $sql="

    UPDATE engine4_event_membership a
    INNER JOIN engine4_event_events b ON b.event_id = a.resource_id
    SET a.points = a.points + case b.prize 
    WHERE a.points = max(a.points) AND b.event_id = '{$this->event->getIdentity()}';

    ";
```

Comment: remove case from b.prize as @zerkms already mentioned

Comment: Your code may be vulnerable to SQL injection, if $this->event->getIdentity() can be a string in any circumstance.

Comment: the "case" I forgot to delete it... I was writting an if else statment but I didnt use it.. "end" should be used at the end if you use case... im getting this error now without the case.. Error: Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the data structure correctly, you can do this with a correlated subquery in the WHERE clause.

You are updating the membership table where resource_id is the input identity.  You are looking for record(s) that have the maximum points.  The following should do this:

```
UPDATE engine4_event_membership a join
       engine4_event_events b
       on b.event_id = a.resource_id
    SET a.points = a.points + b.prize 
    WHERE a.resource_id = '{$this->event->getIdentity()}' and
          a.points = (select max(a2.points)
                      from engine4_event_membership a2
                      where a2.resource_id a.resource_id
                     )
```

This will probably get the same MySQL error.  So, the WHERE clause needs to be moved to the joins:

```
UPDATE engine4_event_membership a join
       engine4_event_events b
       on b.event_id = a.resource_id join
       (select resource_id, max(points) as maxpoints
        from engine4_event_membership
        group by resource_id
       ) amax
       on a.resource_id = amax.resource_id and
          a.points = amax.points
    SET a.points = a.points + b.prize 
    WHERE a.resource_id = '{$this->event->getIdentity()}'
```

The inability to use the target table in a correlated subquery is a limitation in MySQL.

Comment: I can use  a2.resource_id = '{$this->event->getIdentity()}' at the end but still getting error:                                                                Error: You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Is that for the second version?

Comment: this works.. se4   
UPDATE engine4_event_membership a join
       engine4_event_events b
       on b.event_id = a.resource_id join
       (select resource_id, max(points) as maxpoints
        from engine4_event_membership
        group by resource_id
       ) amax
       on b.event_id = amax.resource_id and a.points = maxpoints
    SET a.points = a.points + b.prize 
    WHERE a.resource_id = '{$this->event->getIdentity()}'